# VBA codes: hides but won't unhide rows

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I have read a number of posts about hiding rows in Excel, and they all helped me with the hiding, but I still don't seem to find any solutions for why it will not UNHIDE.

I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("D116:D" & LastRow)
   If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If I start with some 1 and some 0 values, then the code successfully hides the rows with value 0, AND also continues to be active, ensuring that any values I later change from 1 to 0 are automatically hidden.

However, the values that were initially 0, once changed to 1, will not UNHIDE automatically. This is a big problem because I intend to start with all zero values, and then unhide rows as these values change to 1 or greater than 1. It's worth of note that these values in column D are references to somewhere else in the same spreadsheet (just for instance =N100), so that I can control the values even when the rows are hidden. I didn't think the use of a formula was a problem because it can still respond to dynamic changes to HIDE (when changed from 1 to 0), just not to UNHIDE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `However, the values that were initially 0, once changed to 1, will not UNHIDE automatically.` - replace `ElseIf c.Value > 1 Then` with `ElseIf c.Value >= 1 Then`

Comment: Or just remove the "elseif" and use "else".. If you only have zero or one, then you don't need an elseif..

Comment: Thank you both, the right code was indeed "if > 0", as I can have values from 0 to 5, and rows should only hide for values =0. The problem remains....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to show a row in VBA, what you have looks right to show a row.   But when I was ever unsure how to do something, I would record a macro to do what I wanted to achieve and then just review the code that excel generates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped. Thanks to Ads help I created a macro, and from that code I got the line that I was missing: Activate. The code now works as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("D116:D" & LastRow)
   If c.Value = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
        c.Activate
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```